# Going from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

[This book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430240296) works with *Eclipse*, but I'm programming in *Android Studio*. The third chapter describes the transformation of the class into *Activity*. Do you know how to do it in *Android Studio*?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code remains the same both on Eclipse and Android Studio. Some of the menu items also are similar or at least have the same terminology, so it shouldn't be very difficult.

As for the part where you add the `Activity` in the Manifest, you can simply add this

```
<activity android:name="YourPackageName"></activity>
```

and replace `YourPackageName` with the actual package name of the activity in question to get this done. This gets added before `</application>`